# Add an image inside a scrollView from another class?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I m trying to add an image as a subview to scrollview outlet that exist in another class

I did create an object within my external class for the parent class where the  scrollView outlet exists

```
var imageClassName = ImageViewController()
```

but when ever I try to add an an image to the scroll view

```
imageClassName.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
```

I get the following error
**"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"**

I also tried adding an optional at the end but still get the same error

```
imageClassName.scrollView?.addSubview(imageView)
```

any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (probably) a common misconception. When I started out, I had this problem too.

Imagine you being, rather than an iOS Developer, a miracle real-world product designer. You designed the blueprints for a magical box that has the user put in photos and then scroll through it(kind of like a magical collage). You show 100 people in a focus group and 95 say they would like that. Then you send the blueprint to a manufacturing company where it produces 100's of identical products. This is similar to your scenario.

Your `ImageViewController.swift` is like the blueprints. Making a new instance of it by itself is like saying: "Put an image into the magicBox's blueprints". iOS has *no* idea which `UIViewController` with class `ImageViewController` to put the picture in, since you can reuse it infinitely many times. You need to specify *which* one your want(even though you probably have only one)

Therefore, you must:

1. Go into your storyboard
2. Select the target `ImageViewController`
3. Click on the third icon from the left on the right toolbar
4. Enter an id(like "ImageVC1") in the "Storyboard ID" section
5. Replace `var imageClassName = ImageViewController()` with:

   `var imageClassName: ImageViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("id you entered in step 4") as! ImageViewController`

And you're good!

Comment: This is by far the best explanation. I clearly understand the concept. Thanks! BobRon

Comment: No problem! You don't know how long this played me back when I started out in Swift